# Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException:

Tags: magento2

Hello i just created new module i tryed to install but i got this after i deleted module but still this error....

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Can't create directory /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Directory/Helper/Data/. in [Magento\Directory\Helper\Data\Proxy] in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:115 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Directo...') #1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Directo...') #2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Directo...') #3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Relations/Runtime.php(38): class_exists('Magento\Directo...') #4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(166): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime->has('Magento\Directo...') #5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(160): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->_inheritInterception('Magento\Directo...') #6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framewo in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on line 115

Comment: Its a permission issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run following code from your root magento dir from ssh

```
sudo chmod -R 777 generated/
```

Comment: well now i cant do reindex
http://prntscr.com/kom9ii

Comment: please check by adding php before bin/magento

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kon6go

Comment: now cache folder permission issue. please run sudo chmod -R 777 var/cache

Comment: Anyone help me how to give permission in wamp windows?

Answer (score 0):

Directory permission error, can not write to generated directory

```
chmod 770 /var/www/html/generated
```

Reference https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Comment: well i set in html folder 777 and it works.. but i cant do reindex via cli.... yesterday i got that error https://prnt.sc/koaqik

and now i got this http://prntscr.com/koluf6